# Forms not sending radio button value

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

actually am getting a small problem with my forms. Its not sending the radio button value. Can anyone help me please? Thankss.. Here is my code

```
    <form action="php/editmain.php" method="post">
                            <td>
                            <input type="textbox" name="title" placeholder="<?php echo $result_poi['Title'];?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="mainid" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-bolt"><img src="icons/acc.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-bars"><img src="icons/apartment.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-glass"><img src="icons/bars.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-book"><img src="icons/books.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-camera"><img src="icons/camera.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-globe"><img src="icons/earth.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-music"><img src="icons/entertain.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-building-o"><img src="icons/estate.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-plus-square"><img src="icons/health.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-hospital-o"><img src="icons/hospital.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-gittip"><img src="icons/massage.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-medkit"><img src="icons/medicalspas.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-home"><img src="icons/museums.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-picture-o"><img src="icons/parks.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-map-marker"><img src="icons/places.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-leaf"><img src="icons/playgrounds.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-circle-o"><img src="icons/playgrounds2.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-cogs"><img src="icons/recreation.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-road"><img src="icons/road.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-shopping-cart"><img src="icons/shopping.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                                <li><input type="radio" name="icons" value="fa fa-flag"><img src="icons/sports.png" height="18px" width="18px"></img></li></br>
                            </td>   
                            <td class="center">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Update">


                            </td>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please show your `php/editmain.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code here and did not see any error, the html is sending data. Maybe there is a problem with the code that is receiving data.

```
// editmain.php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['icons'])) {  // Checks if the parameter exists.
        $icons = $_POST['icons'];  // Stores parameter in a variable.
        echo $icons;  // Print the selected radio value.
    }
?>
```

Comment: Am getting
Notice: Undefined index: icons in C:\xampp\htdocs\DIRECTORY\masterzone\php\editmain.php on line 6

Comment: yes, and nothing is being displayed when i put your code as apparently the form has not submit the radio button value. Could it be my css affecting it?

Comment: CSS may not be affecting your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have variables in your html, are these variables set?

```
<input type="textbox" name="title" placeholder="<?php echo $result_poi['Title'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="mainid" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
```

$result_poi and $id are set?